# Error en instalación Crystal Reports Runtime

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

[image: Error instalacion CR Runtime 13.0.13]

Estoy instalando los paquetes CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13 y CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_13 en un Windows 10 pro y me encuentro con el error que adunto.

"Failed to register. HRESULT -2147010895"

Estoy instalando con el usuario administrador del dominio. Tengo el Framework 4.0 instalado y también he instalado el VS 2015 C++ runtime ya que había leído que podía ser la causa del error pero sigue fallando.

Comment: Mira [aquí un información](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1122647)  o [esta otra información](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23718399/secldap-dll-failed-to-Register.html) quizás puedas encontrar alguna respuesta que resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Había consultado esa pagina pero no ha habido suerte con las soluciones aportadas.

Comment: Lamento no poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me ha funcionado. Lo que he hecho ha sido activar el UAC que lo tenía desactivado y reiniciar. Después me ha dejado instalar sin problema punto no sé muy bien el motivo o si realmente lo que he hecho ha funcionado pero 1 dejo mi experiencia por si alguien le es útil.